# OutOfMemory on Gzip decompress

Tags: android, crash, compression, retrofit

im sending large json to device thru request response and normally the size is around 5mb, so i decided to use GZIP and this dropped from 5mb to less than 1mb

The problem is that im getting OutOfMemory and i dont know WHERE EXACTLY ITS HAPPENING (i know its inside the connection/response handler but its a little aleatory where, i know out of memory can pop from anywhere when memory is low, but i think this is the main source)

Using retrofit i receive:

```
{ data: gzipBase64String }
```

than i decompress it using one method to decompress the base64 string and the other to return the GZIPInputStream

```
  public static GZIPInputStream getByteArrayFromGzippedBase64(String base64) throws IOException {
        if(base64 != null) {
            try {
                byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
                if (data != null) {
                    return getGzipInputStreamFromByteArray(data);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

  public static GZIPInputStream getGzipInputStreamFromByteArray(byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
        final int BUFFER_SIZE = 32;
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
        GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(is, BUFFER_SIZE);
        return gis;
    }
```

and i handle this GZIPInputStream using a JsonReader:

```
reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(Utils.getByteArrayFromGzippedBase64(response.body().data)));
```

and then put it inside a object

```
body = gson.fromJson(reader, SyncDayjourneysResponse.class);
```

why its not working since i was hoping that this dont load all object to memory at once?

Comment: "Using retrofit i receive: `{ data: gzipBase64String }`" -- right there, you are wasting a lot of memory. Your Web service should be returning the GZip data directly, not base64-encoded, not wrapped into some JSON. And now you have to decode the base64 on the device. So you have already blown through 2.3MB of heap space, in the form of a 1MB `byte[]` and a ~1.3MB `String` of base64-encoded data that created that `byte[]`. As Mike points out, `getGzipInputStreamFromByteArray()` will return a 5MB `byte[]`. Any one of those three huge allocations might trigger an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: @CommonsWare i got it, but sending even the GZIP directly (not base64) it will consume less memory on decoding or the problem still exist?! in this moment im searching thru retrofit something like this (considering to not split the data across multiple GET)

Comment: "or the problem still exist?" -- the problem will still exist, though it will be a bit less likely (and your code will run faster). "considering to not split the data across multiple GET" -- IMHO, that makes no sense. That is akin to saying that we should not have PNG and JPEG images on the Web, and that every Web page should have base64-encoded images in its `<img>` tags. If you want to do one GET request, get rid of the embedded GZip in the JSON, return the full JSON dataset, and have your Web server GZip the entire response.

Comment: yes i agree, for a quick fix (not permanent i hope) i will use the encoded gzip and get rid ot the other things and will plan multiple get services! thank you for the clarification =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Utils.getByteArrayFromGzippedBase64(response.body().data)` definitely looks like something that would build the entire 5 MB array in memory, and

`body = gson.fromJson(reader, ...);` also definitely looks like something that would generate an entire greatbighuge JSON object that corresponds to a whole 5 megabytes worth of JSON text in memory.

I would recommend seeing if there is any way to do deflating on-the-fly instead of creating a byte array to contain the entire deflated content.

Other than that, you might want to look into breaking down your single greatbighuge JSON object into smaller objects.

Comment: Thank you @Mike Nakis,  to append with this answer: https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/http/Streaming.html